# How to sort a data frame in Python when asking multiple variables using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, group-by

I am trying to find the average number of gallons of Fireball Cinnamon Whisky sold in each county in IA using a data frame (.csv) file already organized using Python with Pandas and Numpy. I am fairly new to Python and am still learning.

I have tried this

```
IALiquor.groupby(["Item Description"])["Volume Sold (Gallons)"].mean()["Fireball Cinnamon Whisky"]
```

but this only gives me the mean of "Fireball Cinnamon Whisky" sold and not sorted by counties outputting a single number.

I have also tried this

```
IALiquor.groupby(["County"])["Volume Sold (Gallons)"].agg({"mean"})
```

which outputs the list of counties with the mean "Volume Sold (Gallons)" but not the mean of "Fireball Cinnamon Whisky".

I can do both of the functions separately but I  cannot figure out how to combine the two and the documentation online isn't very helpful. I have also tried incorporating the sort_values function but can't seem to get that to work either(probably implementing incorrectly).

Thanks for any help.

[Here is what the data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQyOS.png)

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you share a sample of the data so we know what we are dealing with. I am not sure which of your columns has the country names and if `"Fireball Cinnamon Whisky"` is a column or a description. If you want to sort by counties add `.sort_values(by='counties column', ascending=False)`

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the data. the county name is under the "County" column and the "Fireball Cinnamon Whisky" is a description under the column "Item Description".

Comment: Hi, you should first select all the entry corresponding to "Fireball Cinnamon Whisky" and apply the groupby and mean then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IALiquor.groupby(["county","Item Description"])\
.agg(avg_volume_sold = ("Volume Sold (Gallons)", 'mean')).reset_index()\
.query("`Item Description` == 'Fireball Cinnamon Whisky'")\
.sort_values(by=['county','Item Description'])
```

Added `sort_values` so you know how to implement that.

AS @jlesueur mentioned, you could also select records corresponding to `Fireball Cinnamon Whisky` before grouping and averaging, like this:

```
IALiquor.query("`Item Description` == 'Fireball Cinnamon Whisky'")\
.groupby(["county","Item Description"])\
.agg(avg_volume_sold = ("Volume Sold (Gallons)", 'mean')).reset_index()
```

You can also select records corresponding to cinnamon whisky using:

```
IALiquor[IALiquor["Item Description"] == 'Fireball Cinnamon Whisky']
```

or using `.loc`

```
IALiquor.loc[IALiquor["Item Description"] == 'Fireball Cinnamon Whisky', :]
```